# Facebook Event Json Mesage- how can i get it?

Tags: json, facebook

I would like to ask if someone know how to grab a facebook event json message. It doesnt matter if it has to happen programatically. I just want to be able to read the message one way or another.

thanks in advance.

P.s. Maybe an awful question but here you go !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had to code a small chunk of code to parse a json-encapsulated message. However recently I found out there's a handy solution for it if you use Java

> Resty is a small, convenient library
>   to talk to RESTful services from Java.
>   It’s surprisingly complex to do the
>   simplest HTTP calls with the standard
>   Java library. Resty hopes to change
>   that.

http://beders.github.com/Resty/Resty/Overview.html

```
    Resty r = new Resty();
Object name = r.json("http://ws.geonames.org
   /postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=66780&country=DE")
  .get("postalcodes[0].placeName");
```

Just import a small jar lib and you'll be surprised. I currently use this class for getting info from url API.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if parsing information from a json message is what you want. I assume you already knew how to fetch that json text from provided APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question was basically how to fetch them from facebook. Specifically, the JSON of events(i mean facebook events for concerts etc). Though, i liked the answer you provided since i didnt know resty. If you can also help with the fetching, i will be very glad !

Comment: Are you a facebook apps developer? I'm not a FB developer so I don't know much about this issue. However I recommend you to read carefully their docs. To get event messages, you should call method **events.get** following their provided API url. The following address contains a lot of example:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.get/

Comment: I tried this querry "https://api.facebook.com/method/events.get?uid=aff&access_token=..." 
and got 
{"error_code":100,"error_msg":"qe does not resolve to a valid user ID","request_args":[{"key":"method","value":"events.get"},{"key":"uid","value":"qe"},{"key":"start_time","value":"12"},{"key":"access_token","value":"137932892931960|2.DnP4uVoWvfkFLB_lqM8ZSg__.3600.1303228800.0-678854083|PsCRiqUdG3nQI6FttAb3lXrVWZI"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}

Try it yourself, I think the method is quite simple.

Comment: Thanks again for the new answers ! No , i am not a fb dev and unfortunatelly not vey familiar with JSON technologies. Maybe its simpler than i thought but i was hoping to get the answer to the question without having me thinking :) After all, if we all get focused on one thing, then production gets slower. About the app, i just want to make a java app for event manipulation for the fun of it ! Nothing concrete or time/money dependent.